Ferrite Bead 2 Stage Pi Filter(s) before MOSFET PS(S) and on OUTPUT

SCHEMATIC as shown in picture above.   What is the 3 two stage pi filters with ferrite beads as the inductors doing and are they needed for the both the V+ (VIN 28VDC), GND, and OUT (0-7.5VDC).
I am trying to understand why this would be a 2 stage pi filter using the same ferrite twice.
The yellow sections are 2 power supplies using MOSFET(S), DIODE(S) and RESISTOR(S).  One of them is approximately 7.25 VDC and the other is approximately 4.5 VDC.
The ferrite beads L12, L11, L1, L2, L22, L21 are all the following.   Wurth 742792141
The capacitors C13, C12, C11, C1, C2, C3, C23, C22, C21 are all very high voltage 2kV or 1.5kV as follows
https://connect.kemet.com:7667/gateway/IntelliData-ComponentDocumentation/1.0/download/datasheet/C1206C102JGRACTU
https://www.yageo.com/upload/media/product/productsearch/datasheet/mlcc/UPY-NP0X7R_HV_1KV-to-3KV_13.pdf
https://connect.kemet.com:7667/gateway/IntelliData-ComponentDocumentation/1.0/download/datasheet/C1206C222KFRACTU
amperage on the input and output are both very low 1-3 mA.
BASICALLY MY QUESTIONS ARE AS FOLLOWS:

does this 2 stage pi filter make sense and what is doing compared to a single pi filter.
is the filter needed on the output if the output is coming from an OPAMP
should there be a single stage pi filter after the PS(S)
is there anything these filters do for lightning protection or external line cleanup ext.
anything else that could help explain the purpose and function of this.

Thanks so much for the help.

What connects to either side of the circuit shown? Understand that EMC is a complex, interconnected topic, and EMC problems are holistic in nature.  There is generally very little that can be said about a problem without also completely describing the setup and environment.

Why not use a simulator to find the answers? I mean, all we see is a schematic with no explanation of expected performance or, where the schematic came from. What can be you realistic expectations in asking these questions?

answers to comments is the right is input in to a sensor that outputs voltage.
the power supplies supply 3 ics total.  4.5 vdc to a sesnsor conditoner and eeprom and 7.25 to a linear doubling opamp.
